# How to set up conversion tracking for hotel campaigns using Google Tag Manager (instead of gtag.js)?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, gtag.js, google-ads-api

Unfortunately, built in GTM tag "Google Ads Conversion Tracking" doesn't support setting special Hotel properties (used in Google Hotel Ads):

```
'items': [{
  'id': 'PARTNER_HOTEL_ID',
  'start_date': 'CHECK_IN_DATE',
  'end_date': 'CHECK_OUT_DATE'
}]
```

Official docs are here:
https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/9244174?hl=en
Instructions are for gtag.js and GTM is only mentioned in an unclear way (at least for me):

> If you're using Google Tag Manager, you can implement the gtag.js for
> Hotel Ads by using the custom HTML tagging option to add the booked
> hotel variables. The global site snippet should be set to run on all
> pages, including the confirmation pages, and the event snippet should
> run on the confirmation pages only. We do not recommend using the
> Google Ads template because it does not support all variables for
> hotel campaign reporting.

If I understood correctly, I should install gtag using GTM and then the tracking using gtag? It sounds weird...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to solve your need the documentation says to install the `gtag.js` snippet with a custom HTML tag in GTM instead of directly on the page.